# How do I make an EBS volume into a bootable AMI? (Created instance from public instance. Now I want to make it my own....)

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, amazon-ebs

I created an Amazon Instance from a public EBS-backed AMI.

I Installed it, and made my changes.

Now I want to take this EBS volume with my changes and make that into a bootable AMI. How do I do this?

From the Amazon web console, it doesn't have any option to take an arbitrary snapshot or EBS volume and boot from that....It has to be a special "AMI" volume. How do I bless an EBS volume to make it an AMI?

Answer (score 0):

The process to create your own AMI from an EBS backed [Amazon EC2](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/) instance is nowadays straight forward, there are two options:

### Amazon EC2 API Tools

How to achieve this via the [Amazon EC2 API Tools](http://aws.amazon.com/developertools/351) is outlined in the [Creating Amazon EBS-Backed AMIs](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/creating-an-ami-ebs.html):

> You can create an AMI that uses an Amazon EBS volume as its root
>   device with Windows or Linux/UNIX operating systems.
>
> [...] You start with an Amazon EBS-backed AMI (for
>   example, one of the public AMIs that Amazon provides), and modify it
>   to suit your particular needs. [...]
>
> When you have a running instance in the state you want, use
>   ec2-create-image or CreateImage and specify the instance ID. Amazon
>   EC2 powers down the instance, takes images of any volumes that were
>   attached, creates and registers the AMI, and then reboots the
>   instance. [...]

The (few and simple) detailed steps to achieve this from the command line are outlined on this page as well.

### AWS Management Console

How to achieve this via the [AWS Management Console](http://aws.amazon.com/console/) is outlined in [Creating an Image from a Running Instance](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/Tutorial_CreateImage.html):

> This section walks you through creating an Amazon EBS-backed AMI from
>   a running Amazon EBS-backed instance. If you don't have a running
>   instance that uses an Amazon EBS volume for the root device, you must
>   start one up (for instructions, see Launching, Stopping, and
>   Starting).

This is even simpler than the command line to get started, but has the drawback that the instance *must* be powered down, whereas this is optional (though the default as well) when using the command line approach above:

> **Tip**
>   As part of the process of creating your new AMI, we power down the instance and then reboot it. If you prefer the instance not be
>   rebooted, you can use the Amazon EC2 command line tools to create the
>   image instead of the AWS Management Console. The ec2-create-image
>   command has a --no-reboot option. When you use the option, the file
>   system integrity on the created image can't be guaranteed. [...]